# How to remove brackets in feign client response header

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-cloud-feign

I have a feign client connects to an external service and retrieve the response. All works fine.

```
val response: ResponseEntity<String> = externalService.send(request)
logger.debug("response.headers, ${response.headers}")
```

The output is

```
response.headers, URL: [some_value]
```

Why there are brackets contains in the `[some_value]` ? I am expecting a plain string. I am sure that the original value does not contain this brackets. But when I read the header it contains.

Comment: Those brackets are probably just an artifact of how Spring's [`HttpHeaders`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html) toString() method works. If you want the raw values (plural, because header names may be repeated), you'll probably need to use methods other than toString(). Since HttpHeaders implements [`MultiValuedMap`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html), you could try getting the header values using methods of that interface.

Comment: @dnault  Is there a good way to read it without getting those? I tried couple of ways but I get those.